# Hook on object in std::list. Pointer or iterator?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, iterator

I looked for the same type of question but I didn't find the answer to my question (existential one):
What type of hook should I choose to keep control over an object in a list?
I waver between pointer and iterator.

The container is filled at the beginning and shouldn't be resized after that. The hook is the way I use to switch between my objects at the whim of user and manipulating only one variable in my algorithm.

In all cases, I must go through an iterator to find the right object to hook. But which one is the best practice/use?

```
// 10 object list
std::list <Object> List(10);

std::list <Object>::iterator it = List.begin();
Object *pt = NULL;

// Select the 3rd object
advance(it, 3);
pt = &(*it);

// Access to object member...
it->member;
pt->member;
```

Pointers allow not to access to neighbours, contrary to iterators, but may be unsafe.
What's the best pratice?

Comment: Unlike most standard containers, in `std::list` an iterator is never invalidated unless the corresponding element is erased, so it's just as (un)safe as a raw pointer but with the additional benefit, as you said, to be able to iterate starting from the current item. Since iterators are very lightweight objects, choosing either one won't have any impact on the performance so it's really up to you.

Comment: if the container is not changed after it has been filled, and considering the access pattern in your example, you might consider using a `std::vector` with which you access becomes `vec[3]` and this will give you the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing pointers or iterators into a container is quite risky because you might find they're invalid by the time you use them (i.e. if the container or the data changes).

A more generalised and robust approach might be to use a map instead of a list. Every value is identified by a key (of whatever type you like), and you can easily store the keys and check whether or not they're valid before you use them, e.g.:

```
std::map<int, std::string> data;

// Add stuff to the map
data[5] = "blah";
data[27] = "foo";

// Check if a key exists
if (data.find(31) == data.end()) {
    // Key 31 does NOT exist
} else {
    // Key 31 DOES exist
}
```

One thing to be aware of though is that maps are ordered by key value. That means if the sequence of elements is important then you'll need to choose your keys carefully.

Comment: I am not familiar with map and set but this seems to be a good substitue of the hook functionnality. I will look into this way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with the "hook".  If you use
an iterator, it can be used as the starting point for moving
forward or backward in the list.  If you use a pointer, you can
also point to objects outside of the list.  In the end, it
depends on how you expect your code to evolve.

Comment: The hook's goal is to provide a constant object that interfaces the object list and my algorithm. It allows to switch between different  objects in a container at the whim of user (in my case the object represents a bench's configuration).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases use references:

```
Object& ref = *it;
ref.member
```

It behaves like a pointer (so feel free to pass it around functions) but you can't do pointer arithmetics on it (`ref++` will actually call the `operator++()` on Object). Also you can't initialize it from null (will be reported as an error when you try to create the reference).

One thing to remember you still need the object to be alocated somewhere. If say some function deletes the Object from List you shouldn't use `ref` anymore.

Comment: References are not useful in my case because the hook is declared at the beginnig of the program, set 'NULL' or 'List.begin()' even if the list is empty and then assign in relation to the user's choice.